# What is this Content-Type all about?

Tags: http, networking, mime-types, content-type

I have searched regarding this content type,Content-Type: application/vnd.google.safebrowsing-update. though some articles are given on  net regarding this type but i still don't understand  :S

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.google.safebrowsing-update
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2011 05:57:44 GMT
Server: Chunked Update Server
Content-Length: 459
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: What do you not understand about `application/vnd.google.safebrowsing-update`? Seems obvious enough to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application/` indicates that the content is intended to be opened by a specific application.

`vnd.` indicates that the MIME-type is defined by a specific vendor. This is useful when creating your own file types for your programs and intend to distribute them online. You can register specific MIME types to open with your program without the possibility of interefering with other opreation.

`google.` is the vendor in this case.

`safebrowsing-update` is the specific type of file from Google. The name is self-explanatory.

Comment: is safebrowsing-update file is always the same? or different everytime?

Comment: If it's the same file (or file type) then yes. Otherwise it could be anything. MIME types are intended to serve as a guideline so that the downloading program knows if it can use it (HTML, images, JS etc) or if it needs help (external player for music, for example)

Comment: ok, please tell me whats the purpose of this type of response packet?

Comment: Yes i know every mime type just indicates whats the type of the response is going through  like text,pdf,amf and so on but what does this response indicate like what is present in its data portion?

Answer (score 1):

The content type tells you that it is application-specific (`application/`) and is an update to Google's Safe Browsing feature.

The `Content-Type` header, in the general, is to inform a client which parser to use for a server's response to a request. For example, a web browser might use one interface to render an RSS feed, another to render an HTML web page, and a third to display a PDF.

In this case, the reply is said to contain information about a list of web sites considered safe or unsafe by Google.